# Set new variable with name of string from existing variable

Tags: bash

I am trying to do something like below:

```
for a in apple orange grape; do
    ${!a}="blah"
done
echo $apple
blah
```

Possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `declare`.

```
for a in apple orange grape; do
    declare "$a=blah"
done
```

Comment: +1; ingenious solution; alternative form that may make what's going on a little clearer: `declare $a='blah'` - there's no need to or point in double-quoting `$a`, because `declare` will not apply expansions to the left side (and anything that truly needs quoting wouldn't work as a variable name anyway).

Comment: Or alternatively to `declare`: `printf -v $a "%s" "blah"`

Answer (score 4):

I wonder if you might want to use [associative arrays](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Arrays) instead:

```
declare -A myarray
for a in apple orange grape; do
    myarray[$a]="blah"
done
echo ${myarray[apple]}
```

Note associative arrays require [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) version 4.0 or greater.